# How to render some routes and serve a SPA from a CDN on another route with Express

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

I am using node.js and express to render some pages like home pages and some other SEO routes.

For a specific route I want to serve a react SPA which I host on a CDN.
on that page I load the main.js from the cdn, but it is trying to load the rest of the assets from the node server, not the CDN.

One solution is to serve the SPA from node, but I know serving assets from node on production is not the best practice.

So how do I render some routes locally with node, and proxy another to a SPA application?
Do I need a third server for reverse proxy?

Thank you!

Comment: In your `main.js`, when you reference to assets, prepend the CDN domain to URLs?

Comment: thanks, but that is not working...